# How to implement tree menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement tree menu for this example. First all has to be closed.
When we click facility Bulidngs has to appear intree format and then if we click XYZ building Floors has to apper. like that....

i have tried this code but not working can anyone help me out.

```js
    $('.treemenu').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.subtree');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treemenu">
    <li>Facility
    <ul class="subtree">
    <li>Building
    <ul class="subtree">
     <li>Royal Building</li>
     <li>Taj Building</li>
     <li>XYZ Building
      <ul class="subtree">
       <li>Floors
        <ul class="subtree">
         <li>1st Floor</li>
         <li>2nd Floor</li>
         <li>3rd Floor</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Try `jqxTree` from `jQWidgets`

Comment: Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/2858/

Comment: use Bootstrap css and here is the demo bootstrap gives http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hide all subtrees.
2. Add js that will toggle subtrees on parent item click.

```html
<style>
    .subtree{
        display: none;
    }
    .treeitem{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.treeitem').click(function () {
            $(this).next('ul.subtree').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<ul class="treemenu">
    <li><span class="treeitem">Facility</span>
        <ul class="subtree">
            <li><span class="treeitem">Building</span>
                <ul class="subtree">
                    <li>Royal Building</li>
                    <li>Taj Building</li>
                    <li><span class="treeitem">XYZ Building</span>
                        <ul class="subtree">
                            <li><span class="treeitem">Floors</span>
                                <ul class="subtree">
                                    <li>1st Floor</li>
                                    <li>2nd Floor</li>
                                    <li>3rd Floor</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, hide all `.subtree` then on click of `li` show `ul` child of it.

```js
$(".subtree").hide();
$('.treemenu li').click(function () {
  $(this).children('ul.subtree').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treemenu">
  <li>Facility
    <ul class="subtree">
      <li>Building
        <ul class="subtree">
          <li>Royal Building</li>
          <li>Taj Building</li>
          <li>XYZ Building
            <ul class="subtree">
              <li>Floors
                <ul class="subtree">
                  <li>1st Floor</li>
                  <li>2nd Floor</li>
                  <li>3rd Floor</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can we Collapse..? if click facility all has to collapse @mohammad

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSTree library for this. Its documentation is available [here](https://www.jstree.com/). Its a fully customized and easy to easy to use library.

Answer (score 1):

Found this example :

```
$('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
  height: '300px',
  width: '300px',
  theme: 'energyblue'
});
$('#Remove').jqxButton({
  height: '25px',
  width: '100px',
  theme: 'energyblue'
});
$('#Remove').click(function () {
  var selectedItem = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('selectedItem');
   if (selectedItem != null) {
    // removes the selected item. The last parameter determines whether to refresh the Tree or not.
    // If you want to use the 'removeItem' method in a loop, set the last parameter to false and call the 'render' method after the loop.
    $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('removeItem', selectedItem.element, false);
    // update the tree.
    $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('render');
}
});
$('#jqxTree').on('removed', function (event) {
   alert("You removed  item");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JbArT/29/)